# french accents giving "<?>" in http responses with correct charset (Java)

Tags: java, http, encoding, special-characters, charset

Calling an API that returns french sentences, all the accented characters are displayed like `<?>` in my java code, even if the charset is well defined (application/json;charset=iso-8859-1).

Using postman or my web browser, I don't face any problem.
I also tried to call the API with a `Content-Type` header with the value `application/json;charset=UTF-8` or `application/json;charset=iso-8859-1` but the problem remains the same.
Any idea ?

`response.getBody()` gives:

```
{"sentences":[{"fr_value":"il �tait loin","dz_value":"kaan b3id","additional_information":{"personal_prounoun":"HE","verb":"�tre","adjective":"loin","tense":"pass�"}}],"count":1}
```

`new String(response.getBody().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` gives exactly the same.

[image]

I'm using scribejava.

Edit: even saving the response in a file and opening it with NotePad++, the result is similar:
[image]

Comment: `application/json;charset=iso-8859-1` is invalid, AFAIK. JSON always uses an UTF encoding (8, 16 or 32) - see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259

Comment: What encoding is set in that IDE/editor you're viewing that in?

Comment: @g00se in UTF-8, but the problem is not only on the IDE but even elsewhere (I actually tweet the value and I still have the <?> problem)

Comment: @Gereon just updated the encoding to `"application/json;charset=UTF-8"` but still the same.

Comment: Might be worth saving it to a file so we can examine it. Might be worth asking whether the the server *already* has it wrong

Comment: @g00se just tried saving the file and opening it with NotePadd++, encoding is UTF-8 but the problem is the same one.

Comment: Can we see it? How do you know it's not like that at the server?

Comment: @g00se just added the screenshot in the initial post.
When I call the API through postman, the answer is OK. From my browser using http://localhost:8080/ , the API response is also correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243558/discussion-between-g00se-and-redouane-b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using the following code :

```
      httpResponse.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      mapper.getFactory().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
```

Comment: Hey! Facing same issue. Postman working fine. So did you made change in API layer on the java side?

Comment: @ParthChokshi yes I only change this part on the java side. Then everything was OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read it as ISO-8859-1. Not sure what then as I don't know what you're doing. My https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/51-transcode-in-java is helpful. With wget:
`wget -O - us-central1-dz-dialect-api.cl… | xcode -ie Latin1` (I made 'xcode' to invoke that Java app)